# Arduino whooping siren sound

Tags: arduino, alarm

I am trying to make an alarm system using Arduino. I would like to have the siren connected to the system be able to output two different types of sounds. A low "beep beep" kind of sound which I know how to do, but I can't figure out how to get the Arduino to emit a "whoop whoop" sound using the tone command or a variant of the tone command or a similar command.

Also on this topic, how would I go about driving a higher power siren/horn using an Arduino? Can I do so using a mosfet transistor the same way I would drive a 12v led?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :-)

EDIT:

This is my main loop that emits the noise:

```
void loop() {
  int i = 200; // The starting pitch
  while(i < 800) {
    i++;
    tone(buzzer, i); // Emit the noise
    delay(5);
  }
  delay(100); // A short break in between each whoop
}
```

Every time the noise emits it make a few (about 3-4) small 'crackles', like distortion. Its not really noticeable with a small piezo directly connected to the Arduino but I suspect when I use a larger sounder and an amplifier it will be more noticeable.

Comment: Second, yes. Just use a transistor. First, could you specify a "whoop whoop" siren? A link to a veido or something. Any code you can show us?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of a video,https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aNnrD5fxB14

Comment: Have you tried something like a loop from 0 to 255 to 0 with an analogWrite in the alarm's pin? Choose a cycle time of a 'whoop' and put delay between analogWrites...

Comment: When I use a loop it works but I can hear a bit of distortion in the sound.

Comment: Please, post a piece of your code. Could be a delay or an incorrect assignment, but without seeing it I can't talk.

Answer (score 4):

I made some code for this for an April fools joke and here it is:

```
void loop {
  // Whoop up
  for(int hz = 440; hz < 1000; hz++){
    tone(speakerPin, hz, 50);
    delay(5);
  }
  noTone(speakerPin);

  // Whoop down
  for(int hz = 1000; hz > 440; hz--){
    tone(speakerPin, hz, 50);
    delay(5);
  }
  noTone(speakerPin);
} // Repeat
```

Where `speakerPin` is the pin connected to your speaker.

Hope this helps.